# Convex subsets of an open set

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and let $Y\subseteq X$ be convex. Can I always construct an open and convex set $Z$ such that $Y\subseteq Z\subseteq X$?

Edit: As Ilya Bogdanov pointed out, the claim is wrong in general. But, what if $X$ is the interior of a finite union of polytopes? Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider a line $y=0$ inside the set $x^2y^2<1$. There also exist bounded examples.

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov Thanks! You mentioned that there exist bounded examples. May I have a counterexample when $X$ and $Y$ are both bounded?

Answer (score 8):

A bounded example:
$$
  X=\left\{(x,y)\colon \sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}<1\right\}, \quad
  Y=\{(x,0)\colon |x|<1\}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will need more restrictions. Currently I may restrict $X$ to be the interior of a finite union of polytopes. Understanding that I may already have asked too much, it would be great if you can give me some hint on that...

Answer (score 5):

On the positive side: if $Y$ is a ***compact*** convex subset of an open set $X$ in a locally convex TVS, then there is an open convex neighborhood $U$ of the origin so small that the open convex set  $Z:=Y+U$ is included in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Yet a bit more on the positive side: If $Y$ is a convex subset of an open **convex** subset $X$ of a normed space, then the set $Z:=\bigcup_{y\in Y}B_y^X$ will do, where $B_y^X$ is the largest open ball centered at $y$ that is contained in $X$.